# String replace \n with <br/> not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Im currently loading some text through XML via my doc class - this text contains \n tags

**XML example:**

What im looking to do is replace \n in my string with

**I've tried a few things:**

```
string = string.split("\n").join('<br/>');
```

and

```
string = string.replace("\n","<br/>");
```

However tracing out **string** afterwards, or just seeing what *myTextField.htmlText = string;* displays, I still see the **\n** tags

Any ideas?

Code illustrated:

```
// The string which contains the XML loaded content
var string:String;

var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
myTextField.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
myTextField.width = 300;
myTextField.border = false;
myTextField.embedFonts = true;
myTextField.multiline = true;
myTextField.wordWrap = true;
myTextField.selectable = false;

myTextField.htmlText = string;

addChild(myTextField);
```

Comment: Maybe try setting a height? Say 200 or something as an example.

Comment: When you say you still see the '\n' tags, you mean it has newlines, right? It's not literally "\n", is it? If it is, try .replace("\\n", "<br/>"); ?

Comment: What I mean is that \n is actually outputting as apart of my text and not being replaced by a <br/> which would instead result as a break in my text

Comment: .replace("\\n", "<br/>"); did the trick! So I was basically missing a "\" weird . Thanks so much izb!

Comment: Actually it seemed to work fine in a case with only one \n however if there are several \n in the same string it will only replace the first one?

Comment: Imm wayy too fast in the comments.

Using .split("\\n").join('<br/>');  did the trick then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```js
string = string.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

This will replace all newlines with `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
str = str.replace("\\n", "\n");
```

OR the following applies to all instances:

```
str = str.split("\\n").join("\n");
```

Try that

Comment: You'll need to escape the \ in the \n

Comment: Hi Lex, and welcome to SO. We don't use signatures here, so I've trimmed that from your answer. Also, if you look at the comments below, you'll see the asker already found a solution to this question, they just neglected to mark it off as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above didnt work for me

```
string = string.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

I was able to do the same thing this way

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(13), "<br>");
```

im using flash cs6-as3

hopefully this helps if the other doesnt work for you